# My cpu does not supprot intel virtualization technology

Tags: android, virtualbox, virtualization, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I have a problem with android devices emulation.

Before I had Windows 7 x64 Ultimate on my labtop and all was fine. 
Now I have updated OS to Windows 10 Pro x64.

When I'm starting genymotion's virtual device from VirtualBox, I'm getting the next error:

```
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Strarting bundled AVD leads to the next message:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I can not install intelhaxm beacuase of my cpu does not support Intel Virtualization Technology and I can not enable it in BIOS.

Also Hyper-V is turned off at this machine.

Why is this happening? And why did it work before? Help me please.

**UPD. Any additional information can be added on your requests.**

Answer (score 1):

You must enable the Hyper-V role before you can create virtual machines on Windows 10. This can be done using the Windows 10 control panel, PowerShell or the Deployment Imaging Servicing and Management tool (DISM).

**Manually Install the Hyper-V role**

Right click on the Windows button and select ‘Programs and Features’.

Select Turn Windows Features on or off.

Select Hyper-V and click OK.

When the installation has completed you are prompted to restart your computer.

**Install Hyper-V with PowerShell**

Open a PowerShell console as Administrator.

Run the following command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All
```

When the installation has completed you need to reboot the computer.

Install Hyper-V with DISM

The Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool or DISM is used to service Windows images and prepare Windows Pre installation environments. DISM can also be used to enable Windows features while the operating system is running. For more information, see DISM Technical Reference.

**To enable the Hyper-V role using DISM:**

Open up a PowerShell or CMD session as Administrator.

Type the following command:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

You can check if your system is compatible by following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility) guide.

Comment: Did you try checking if your system is compatible using the method provided in the link?